# Azure Tomcat Eclipse Deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, azure, deployment

I have an azure server that runs my Tomcat web apps. Everything works well but I find that exporting my war, undeploying, then redeploying the war to Tomcat is a hassle. On my dev environment I run Tomcat within eclipse and have my latest code to run. What would be the problem with running eclipse on my azure server, having Tomcat run within eclipse to run my web apps? This way with any change I can simply git pull my latest code into eclipse and restart tomcat. Is this a bad idea in production and why? If so any recommendations on how to make this easier? I would rather not expose the tomcat manager application to the world so please don't recommend that.

Comment: I fail to understand why Eclipse is in picture, why can't you run the tomcat server separately without eclipse, running a production through an IDE is anyways bad idea.

Comment: I bring up eclipse because on my dev machine Tomcat runs within eclipse and the web apps are always up to date with git within eclipse. I was hoping I could replicate this is production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, the easy way to continuous deployment for Tomcat web apps in Eclipse is using local Git repository.

First, Create a `Dynamic Web Project` with Tomcat in Eclipse. There is a key step for creating project different from normal step. When configuring web module settings, need to set `webapps/ROOT` for Content directory, see below:

[image]

Then, the project structure tree as below:

[image]

Second, Configure the continuous deployment for Azure WebApp on Azure Portal.

[image]

After done above, copy the git clone url for git cmd.

[image]

Until now, open the git bash to push project into Azure. The steps as below.

1. Open the git bash cmd and `cd` into project directory `<app-name>`.
2. `git init`
3. `git add webapps`
4. `git commit -m "Initial Commit"`
5. `git remote add <app-name> <git-clone-url>`
6. `git push <app-name> master`

Now, you can browse `https://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net/` to see it.

For continous developement, you just need to repeat the step 3, 4 and 6.

Comment: I appreciate your thorough answer

Comment: However I meant that I have a virtual machine in azure that I would like to install eclipse on and run web apps from there.

Comment: @Ethan You can use a VM in Azure to install Eclipse and run web apps like doing it on localhost, but it's not a good idea. You shoud do the deployment and development separately on Azure and localhost. If you have to use Azure VM, please refer to the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-tutorial/ to do it like on local.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you elaborate why its a bad idea? I see almost no downfalls to doing so.

Comment: @Ethan Because the environments of development and deployment should be separated alone for running stable, secure and non-interference each other. And the Web App cost less than the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Which is all nice and fine if you are doing development, but for production you shouldn't need the Development Code Environment, rather the production should always contain the runtimes. Which anyways in case of Azure Webapp with Tomcat8 is available (you don't actually need eclipse on  the server). 
I think your worry is that if you use the Azure WebApps than your Tomcat manager will be exposed to the world, if thats the case I suggest you use "Jetty" blade to deploy your app rather then using the Tomcat, if you use Jetty than the basic page would be "Nothing" unless you push code. 
More Detailed overview of Using Azure Webapp deployment with Jetty is Available here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-get-started/