# Azure GIT continous deployment for default Java WebApp (using default Tomcat)

Tags: java, git, maven, tomcat, azure

Currently, when you deploy a Java WebApp using the default Tomcat, the default Tomcat will listen for WAR archives on D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps (See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-add-app/).

The problem is that if you plan to use  continuous deployment through GIT, the new fetched archives will be copied under wwwroot folder, not under wwwroot/webapps, so the default Tomcat can listen on them.

Is there any way in which I can tell the default Tomcat to listen for War archives on a specific folder (e.g wwwroot instead) ?
Are there settings that I can play with?

Having a custom Tomcat (second solution of 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/12/11/use-custom-context-for-azure-tomcat-application.aspx) is not the most optimal solution, since we will have to copy the Tomcat to all deployment slots that we configure (that's error prone). Deployment slots should be as similar as possible.

At the same time, some of the settings from ApplicationSettings won't be applied anymore, since they apply only on the default Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

There is my answer for the other thread that the needs was similar with yours. I think it can help you, please refer to the thread [Azure Tomcat Eclipse Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951613/azure-tomcat-eclipse-deployment).

Based on my understanding, you want to deploy the war file into Azure WebApps thru Azure Git continuous deployment. So you can follow the steps modified from the answered thread above, see below.

1. Open the git bash cmd and make a new directory `webapps` for war files.
2. Copy or export the war file into the directory `webapps`.
3. `git init`
4. `git add webapps`
5. `git commit -m "Something Commit"`
6. `git remote add <app-name> <git-clone-url>`
7. `git push <app-name> master`

> Note: For the variables `<app-name>` and `<git-clone-url>`, you can find them on Azure new portal.

Now, you can browse `https://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net/<war-file-name>` to see it after tomcat unzip the war file to the same name folder automatically.

For continous deployment, you just need to repeat the step 2, 4 and 6.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: So , basically you are building the war file locally and pushing to azure , right ? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of continuous deployment . Ideally when you push the code to azure , isn't it azure's responsibility to build the source code and deploy the war onto the tomcat

Comment: @redeemed Actually, as explained that you can directly deploy the webapp directory via Git. You need to change the `Content directory` name when creating the web project on Eclipse.

Comment: I am not using eclipse . Trying the whole thing from git bash . Created a web app on azure , specified my java run time and tomcat app server . Inside the web app , clicked on continous deployment and mapped Local Git repository , as described over here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/#Step75 . But how do we deploy a dynamic web application using this approach . AFAIK this will let you just copy your source files onto git . How will it run my gradle script and deploy the war file and push to azure under /site/wwwroot/webapps directory